# Analytically estimate joint Von Mises distribution parameters from multiple underlying distributions with arbitrary weights

Tags: joint-distribution, circular-statistics, von-mises-distribution

Given a set of `n` one dimensional (circular) Von Mises distributions, it is possible to randomly sample each distribution (with a different weight, `w`, applied to each distribution) and estimate parameters `mu` and `k` for a single joint distribution.

This is straight-forward using the `r` package `circular`. However, for my real time java implementation, the random sampling and maximum likelihood estimation steps are computationally expensive.

Is it possible to analytically compute parameters `mu` and `k` for this joint distribution? For my application it would be acceptable to make some simplifying approximations that gives close but not identical results to the resampling/MLE approach.

```r
library(circular)

## Helper function to generate a circular object in degrees, 0-360 

circularDeg <- function(x) circular(x, template = "geographics", 
                       units = "degrees", modulo = "2pi")
theta <- circularDeg(seq(from = 0, to = 360,by = 1))

m1 <- circularDeg(180)
k1 <- 2.1
w1 <- 65
dvm1 <- dvonmises(theta, mu = m1, kappa = k1)

m2 <- circularDeg(175)
k2 <- 1.4
w2 <- 55
dvm2 <- dvonmises(theta, mu = m2, kappa = k2)

m3 <- circularDeg(205)
k3 <- 3.1
w3 <- 17
dvm3 <- dvonmises(theta, mu = m3, kappa = k3)

## Sample a joint distribution based on random draws from each 
## distribution with weights
x <- c(rvonmises(ceiling(100000 * w1), m1, k1),
       rvonmises(ceiling(100000 * w2), m2, k2),
       rvonmises(ceiling(100000 * w3), m3, k3))

joint <- mle.vonmises(x)
dvmJoint <- dvonmises(theta, joint$mu, joint$kappa)
```

[image: Example of resampling and MLE results]

### Some explanation of underlying system:

The angle between two sensors, `x`, is fixed, but cannot be directly measured. Based on a physical model, estimates can be made, but measurement noise, external forces, and model errors introduce uncertainty. Each time the system is activated, the `x` can be estimated based on a set of measurements collected, with the dispersion of estimates described by a Von Mises distribution.

The system is then dormant for a period of time, and then periodically re-activated. For each active period, there may be different error biases, number of observations, or noise amplitude. Error biases for each activation differs because system is substantially changed between each activation, and the physics may vary from the simplified model. In addition, some measurement inputs are recalibrated each activation, potentially adding a new bias each activation.

As a result, the mean or dispersion of each observation set may vary, but in the long run, it is believed that a single Von Mises distribution is a fair approximation for model estimates of `x`. The results of resampling and computing a joint distribution using MLE are satisfactory. However, memory and computation constraints make both persisting all the data or using this resampling approach impractical. *That is why I desire an analytic approach.*

### Existing approaches in literature

In researching potential solutions, I came across two papers cited in [GeorgeWQ's answer on another Von Mises related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442106/sum-of-two-von-mises-random-variables/554968#554968): ["Cue Combination on the Circle and the Sphere"](https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2191621) and ["Bearing-only tracking with a mixture of von Mises distributions"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6385600). *(both are available in PDF form for free via Semantic Scholar)* Authors on both implemented a mathematically equivalent approach for the purposes of combining two distributions.

However, the approximation used to calculate kappa yields a joint distribution with a very different dispersion than would be estimated using maximum likelihood estimation, and in cases where the kappa ratio is not equal to 1, the estimate mean also diverges. Further, in cases where more than two distributions are considered, the order with which they are combined has a significant influence on the results.

[image: Proposed equations to estimate kappa and mu]

An example implementation of this approach demonstrates how the kappa calculation approach yields a much tighter dispersion estimate than the underlying data supports.

```r
## Implementation of combination approach proposed in 
## "Cue Combination on the Circle and the Sphere"
## and "Bearing-only tracking with a mixture of von Mises 
##      distributions"
makeJoint <- function(dList = NULL) {
  
  SortOrder <- data.table(Id = seq_len(length(dList)),
                  weight = sapply(dList, `[[`, "weight"),
                  kappa = 
             sapply(dList, `[[`, "kappa"))[order(-weight,-kappa), Id]
  
  for(i in seq_len(length(SortOrder))){
    idx <- SortOrder[[i]]
    m <- as.numeric(dList[[idx]]$mu) * pi / 180
    k <- dList[[idx]]$kappa
    w <- dList[[idx]]$weight
    if(i == 1L){
      M <- m
      K <- k
      W <- w
    } else {
      Error  <- m - M
      M <- M + atan2(sin(Error), (K/k) * (W/w) + cos(Error))
      K <- (K^2 + k^2 + 2 * K * k * cos(Error))^0.5
      W <- W + w
    }
    
    print(paste0("Execution #",i,". sample #", idx,
            " Distribution: m = ", M,", k = ", K))
    
  }
  return(list(mu = circular(M / pi * 180, template = "geographics", 
              units = "degrees", modulo = "2pi"),
              kappa = K,
              weight = W))
  
}

dList <- list(list(mu = m1, kappa = k1, weight = w1),
              list(mu = m2, kappa = k2, weight = w2),
              list(mu = m3, kappa = k3, weight = w3))
Estimate <- makeJoint(dList)
dvmEst <- dvonmises(theta, Estimate$mu, Estimate$kappa)
```

[image: Comparison of resampling vs one proposed analytic approach]

### References

[5](https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2191621): R. F. Murray and Y. Morgenstern, “Cue Combination on the Circle and the Sphere,” Journal of Vision, vol. 10, no. 11, pp. 1–11, 2010. doi: 10.1167/10.11.15 Corpus ID: 18524683

[6](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6385600): I. Marković and I. Petrović, "Bearing-only tracking with a mixture of von Mises distributions," 2012 IEEE/RSJ International Conference on Intelligent Robots and Systems, 2012, pp. 707-712, doi: 10.1109/IROS.2012.6385600.

---

```r
## Plotting Code, Plot #1
plot_ly() |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm1, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 1: m = ",m1,", k = ", k1, ", 
            weight = ", w1), line = list(color = "steelblue", 
            dash = "dot")) |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm2, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 2: m = ",m2,", k = ", k2, ", 
            weight = ",w2),
            line = list(color = "seagreen", dash = "dot"))  |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm3, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 3: m = ",m3,", k = ",k3, ", 
            weight = ",w3),
            line = list(color = "indianred", dash = "dot"))  |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmJoint, 
            name = paste0("Joint: m = ", round(joint$mu,2),", k = ", 
        round(joint$kappa, 3)),
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2)) |> 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = c(0, 360), dtick = 45),
         legend = list(x = 0.5, y = 1.05, xanchor = "center", 
         yanchor =  "bottom")) -> DensityCurves


Hist <- data.table(x)[, .(Count = .N), by = .(x = round(x/2,0)*2)]

plot_ly() |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmJoint, 
            name = paste0("Joint: m = ", round(joint$mu,2),", k = ", 
        round(joint$kappa,3)), yaxis = "y2",
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2), 
            showlegend = FALSE) |> 
  add_bars(data = Hist, x = ~ x, y = ~ Count, color = I("gray"), 
           name = "Histogram of values generated by resampling", 
           yaxis = "y", marker = list(
                   line = list(colot = "black", width = 0.5))) |> 
  layout(hovermode = "closest", barmode = "dodge",
         legend = list(x = 0.5, y = 1.05, xanchor = "center", 
                      yanchor =  "bottom"),
         yaxis = list( showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, 
                      showticklabels = FALSE, title = ""),
         yaxis2 = list(rangemode = "tozero", overlaying = "y2", 
                       side = "left", title = ""),
         xaxis = list(range = c(0,360), dtick = 45)) -> HistogramComparison

subplot(DensityCurves, HistogramComparison, nrows = 2, shareX =  TRUE, 
        titleY = TRUE)
```

```r
## Plotting Code, Plot #2
plot_ly() |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm1, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 1: m = ",m1,", k = ",k1, ", 
                          weight = ", w1),
            line = list(color = "steelblue", dash = "dot")) |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm2, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 2: m = ",m2,", k = ",k2, ", 
                           weight = ", w2),
            line = list(color = "seagreen", dash = "dot"))  |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvm3, 
            name = paste0("Distribution 3: m = ",m3,", k = ",k3, ", 
                          weight = ", w3),
            line = list(color = "indianred", dash = "dot"))  |>
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmJoint, 
            name = paste0("Joint: m = ",round(joint$mu,2),", k = ", 
                      round(joint$kappa,3)),
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2)) |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmEst, 
            name = paste0("Analytic Estimate: m = ", 
                          round(Estimate$mu,2),", k = ", 
                      round(Estimate$kappa,3)),
            line = list(color = "orchid", width = 2)) |> 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = c(0,360), dtick = 45),
         legend = list(x = 0.5, y = 1.05, xanchor = "center", 
                       yanchor =  "bottom")) -> DensityCurves


Hist <- data.table(x)[, .(Count = .N), by = .(x = round(x/2,0)*2)]

plot_ly() |> 
  add_bars(data = Hist, x = ~ x, y = ~ Count, color = I("gray"), 
           name = "Histogram of values generated by resampling", 
           yaxis = "y",
           marker = list(line = list(colot = "black", width = 0.5))) |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmJoint, 
            name = paste0("Joint: m = ", round(joint$mu,2),", k = ", 
        round(joint$kappa,3)), yaxis = "y2",
            line = list(color = "black", width = 2), 
                        showlegend = FALSE) |> 
  add_lines(x = theta, y = dvmEst, 
            name = paste0("Analytic Estimate: m = ", 
            round(Estimate$mu,2),", k = ", round(Estimate$kappa,3)), 
                  yaxis = "y2",
            line = list(color = "orchid", width = 2), 
                        showlegend = FALSE) |> 
  layout(hovermode = "closest", barmode = "dodge",
         legend = list(x = 0.5, y = 1.05, xanchor = "center", 
                       yanchor =  "bottom"),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, showline = FALSE, 
                      showticklabels = FALSE, title = "", 
                       range = c(0,5e5)),
         yaxis2 = list(rangemode = "tozero", overlaying = "y2", 
                       side = "left", title = ""),
         xaxis = list(range = c(0,360), dtick = 45)) -> HistogramComparison

subplot(DensityCurves, HistogramComparison, nrows = 2, shareX =  TRUE,
        titleY = TRUE)
```

Comment: What would the "single joint distribution" be??  It won't be a von Mises distribution!

Comment: Very true, and the toy example I provided most certainly is not fit well by a single Von Mises! In practice, I have an algorithm that periodically fits a Von Mises function to a data set.  Noise is assumed to be random, and the range of underlying distribution means is anticipated to be small. Instead of persisting all the underlying data, on subsequent runs, past result parameters are persisted and used as priors for the subsequent execution predictions.

Comment: I'm afraid that's little to go on.  You acknowledge the distribution won't be von Mises, but your question concerns how to estimate its (nonexistent!) parameters.  What is the actual statistical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to estimate (or should be estimating) the parameters (m1, m2, m3, k1, k2, and k3) from a mixture of von Mises distributions with known weights from a single dataset?  (Or are the weights also unknown?)  If so (a more minor point), if you're looking for a total sample size of n, you should use `rmultinom(1, size=n, prob=c(w1,w2,w3)/(w1+w2+w3))` to generate the 3 sample sizes.

Comment: Given the three prior distributions defined by m/k 1,2,3... and weights 1,2,3... that correspond to the number of observations used to estimate each distribution, I wish to calculate parameters for a single Von Mises distribution that yields similar results to the resampling and MLE approach in the provided example. The individual prior distributions all come from the same process, but represent distinct datasets collected different points in time that have differing amounts of noise or error bias.

Comment: The reason I struggle with that formulation is it looks inherently contradictory.  In general, when two or more of those component distributions are sufficiently narrow and their coefficients are not too small, the mixture will be *multimodal.*  What sense would it make to estimate parameters for a "single" von Mises distribution in such cases??

Comment: Re the edit: that, too, looks self-contradictory.  But if we take the final parts at face value -- namely, you posit a *single* von Mises distribution -- then you should just combine all the data and estimate the parameters.  Since you are not doing this, please tell us specifically *what is it that really changes between "activations"?*

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I hope my edits in response help clarify. Question now include some explanation about might change between "activations", and I updated the toy example to better represent the behavior of the described system. In addition, I added a histogram/density curve plot illustrating why I am satisfied with the results of resampling and computing a single joint distribution using MLE. Computation constraints make persisting all the data or using this resampling approach impractical -- _that is why I desire an alternative analytic approach._

Comment: If you are willing to make simplifying assumptions, have you considered a method-of-moments approach? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters.

Comment: @Avraham Thanks for the suggestion - To get my head wrapped around the idea, I put together a basic implementation of the equations you referenced, _(Gist here: https://gist.github.com/msummersgill/08086ec2d80b4c45f4ad82b406d99d61)_ . However, this approach gives extremely high kappa values, even with a bias correction applied. This makes sense, because only the mean values are considered as implemented, not the underlying distributions. Maybe I'm missing something here, but is there a way to use method-of-moments without needing to sample from the source distributions?